# After upgrading react 16.2 to 16.8, context consumers receive previous value instead of current

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have been using react 16.2 and the context api works as expected with the following structure.

```
const MyContext = createContext(null);

class Provider extends Component {
  state = {
    id: 'A value I set'
  }

  onUpdate = (e) => {
    const { id } = e.dataset
    this.setState({ id });
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { id } = this.state;
    return(
      <MyContext.Provider value={id}>
        {children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

function ConsumerHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  function renderWrappedComponent(id) {
    return <WrappedComponent id={id} />
  }
  return (
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {renderWrappedComponent}
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

When I switched to react 16.8, this code breaks down. Whenever `onUpdate` is invoked, the provider value is updated. However, the consumer never receives the updated value.

If I record a timeline, I can see that react's internal `propagateContextChange` method is called, but nothing happens after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered it on my own! I had only upgraded react, and forgot to also upgrade react-dom. The new version of react relies on the new version of react-dom, so the upgrade broke react context.

Comment: put it the correct answer the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 0):

In 16.8, you'll need to use the context's consumer via a render prop like this...

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
  { context => <YourComponent {...context} /> }
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

This will require you to refactor your HOC as thus...

```
function ConsumerHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  function renderWrappedComponent(id) {
    return (
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        { value => <WrappedComponent id={id} contextValue={value} /> } // if you don't want to pass through all the context's properties, you can chose which props to pass to the wrapped component
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
  return renderWrappedComponent
}
```

Comment: This refactor didn't fix my issue unfortunately.

Comment: where are you calling your HOC?

Comment: I call the HOC as a grandchild, great-grandchild, etc of the Provider. This setup works perfectly in react 16.2. As soon as I upgrade to a new react version, all consumers are behind one step in updates. However, the consumers are all initialized with the correct initial context.

Comment: Also, my context value is just a string, not an object

Comment: I just tried updating the HOC snippet in my answer. Can you try that again and then try to access `contextValue` as a prop in the wrapped component?

Comment: Short answer is no. The reason for the HOC is to add higher order logic that evaluates the context (not shown here) so that I don't have to repeat the same logic in many components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193287/discussion-between-ladi-aden-and-jeremy-gottfried).